# Why can't I use the three method startLeScan,stopLeScan

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

[image]

Why can't I use the three method startLeScan,stopLeScan and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

> Why cant I use the three

Striked out methods are deprecated.

This doesn't mean you cannot use them so by all means just use them if you want. However they are not "supported" anymore since there is a newer API that does it better. Deprecated methods are usually removed from the SDK in the future, so try to never use them unless you must.

Answer (score 1):

The methods are deprecated.

See the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)):

> This method was deprecated in API level 21.
>
> use `startScan(List, ScanSettings, ScanCallback)` instead.